# MKL example code compiles fine with cmake but crashes when run

Tags: c++, cmake, intel-mkl

I am trying to run following example from MKL website.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "mkl_vsl.h"
 
int main()
{
   double r[1000]; /* buffer for random numbers */
   double s; /* average */
   VSLStreamStatePtr stream;
   int i, j;
    
   /* Initializing */        
   s = 0.0;
   vslNewStream( &stream, VSL_BRNG_MT19937, 777 );
    
   /* Generating */        
   for ( i=0; i<10; i++ ) {
      vdRngGaussian( VSL_RNG_METHOD_GAUSSIAN_ICDF, stream, 1000, r, 5.0, 2.0 );
      for ( j=0; j<1000; j++ ) {
         s += r[j];
      }
   }
   s /= 10000.0;
    
   /* Deleting the stream */        
   vslDeleteStream( &stream );
    
   /* Printing results */        
   printf( "Sample mean of normal distribution = %f\n", s );
    
   return 0;
}
```

I am using following CMakeLists.txt file to compile the code.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)
project(rndGen VERSION 0.1.0)

add_executable(rndGen rndGenTest.cpp)

set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ON)
set(MKLROOT "C:/Program\ Files\ (x86)/Intel/oneAPI/mkl/latest")
set(MKLLIB "${MKLROOT}/lib/intel64")

target_include_directories(rndGen
PUBLIC ${MKLROOT}/include
)

target_link_libraries(rndGen
PUBLIC ${MKLLIB}/mkl_intel_ilp64.lib
PUBLIC ${MKLLIB}/mkl_intel_thread.lib
PUBLIC ${MKLLIB}/mkl_core.lib
PUBLIC "C:/Program\ Files\ (x86)/Intel/oneAPI/compiler/latest/windows/compiler/lib/intel64_win/libiomp5md.lib"
)

set(CPACK_PROJECT_NAME ${PROJECT_NAME})
set(CPACK_PROJECT_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION})
include(CPack)
```

As stated in the title, the code crashes. The debugger output from VSCode is as following:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------
You may only use the C/C++ Extension for Visual Studio Code
with Visual Studio Code, Visual Studio or Visual Studio for Mac
software to help you develop and test your applications.
-------------------------------------------------------------------
Loaded 'C:\mklTest\build\Debug\rndGen.exe'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll'. 
Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll'. 
Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\KernelBase.dll'. 
Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\vcruntime140d.dll'. 
Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ucrtbased.dll'. 
The program '[16972] rndGen.exe' has exited with code -1073741515 (0xc0000135).
```

However, the code runs fine when compiled manually in cmd using following command.

```
cl /EHsc rndGenTest.cpp -I "C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\oneAPI\mkl\latest\include" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\oneAPI\mkl\2021.1.1\lib\intel64\mkl_intel_ilp64.lib" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\oneAPI\mkl\2021.1.1\lib\intel64\mkl_intel_thread.lib" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\oneAPI\mkl\2021.1.1\lib\intel64\mkl_core.lib" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\oneAPI\compiler\latest\windows\compiler\lib\intel64_win\libiomp5md.lib"
```

The output of the code is

```
Sample mean of normal distribution = 4.985218
```

I am pretty sure I am missing something in the CMakeLists.txt file. Can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

Thanks for the comments and answers. I tried all of them and none worked. I tried to dig a little bit deeper to find the exact cause of problem. Apparently, the code compiles fine both ways. However, it doesn't work if the exe file is executed directly (executed in cmd directly). It works fine if I first open the oneAPI command prompt and then run the exe. My guess is that there is some environment variable or runtime library which is not available to the exe. If so, what should I change so that the exe can run on its own (without the need of running oneAPI command prompt)?

Comment: Try running your CMake build with the ninja generator and post the output of `ninja -v`. Also, raise your minimum CMake version to 3.18, which is what ships with Visual Studio these days

Comment: You should also be using find_package(BLAS) with BLA_VENDOR set to `Intel10_64ilp`

Comment: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindBLAS.html

Comment: Lastly you should never ever put absolute/system paths in your CMakeLists.txt. If you ever find yourself doing that you should instead be asking (maybe here on SO): "how should I do this correctly?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in that case, you may try to relink the test with sequential mkl's library (mkl_sequential.lib instead of mkl_intel_thread.lib ) and try to execute directly in cmd. Or just put libiomp5md.dll into exe file directory.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I added the redist folder from oneAPI compiler to `PATH` and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you're observing binary incompatibility between 32-bit and 64-bit libraries. You're linking against `mkl_intel_ilp64.lib`, but you don't have the symbol `MKL_ILP64` defined. In particular, this macro defines the size of `MKL_INT` type: it has 64 bits when `MKL_ILP64` is defined and 32 bits otherwise. No wonder that trying to call `ILP64` library functions results in a runtime crash.

Add the following line to your CMakeLists.txt file:

```
target_compile_definitions(rndGen PUBLIC MKL_ILP64)
```

https://software.intel.com/sites/products/mkl/mkl_link_line_advisor.htm

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did what you suggested. However, the problem persisted. The problem seems to be with how the exe file is executed. When I first run the oneAPI command prompt and then execute the exe, it works fine. However, if I run the exe directly in cmd, it crashes. Are there any runtime environment variables or libraries which needs to be defined?

Comment: @JoshiVatsal Do you have MKL DLLs in `PATH`? Maybe MKL still tries to load some DLLs?

Comment: Yes, I did have MKL DLLs in `PATH`. However, it still didn't work. What the code was really looking for was `libiomp5md.dll` which exists in the oneAPI's compiler redist folder. I added it to the path and it worked fine. Thanks for help.